# Django query - count up to 10 votes from one IP

Tags: django, orm

let's say I have a simple voting form with different answers.
the people can vote multiple times from one IP. I can easily find how many votes a given answer has got - `a.vote_set.all().count()` (no limit of votes from 1 IP) I can also find out how many votes there were, given the limit 1 vote from 1 IP - `a.vote_set.all().values('ip').distinct().count()` (limit of votes from one IP =1)
How to get the sum of votes for a given answer provided that I want count up to 10 votes from 1 IP (limit=10)?

To clarify my question: I need a Django orm query to get all the votes for a given answer - but with this condition, that I want to count up to 10 votes from one IP. Example:
Answer A got in total 100 votes. The 100 votes came from the following IP's (either one person voted or couple of them who shared common public IP):

> 1) 120.x.x.x - 20 votes 2) 121.x.x.x - 50 votes 3) 122.x.x.x - 10
>   votes 4) 123.x.x.x - 5 votes 5) 124.x.x.x - 15 votes

I want the query to return 45 votes: 10 votes from IP 1) (10, not 20, because 10 is a limit), 10 from 2), 10 from 3) , 5 from 4) and finally 10 from 5.

I don't know beforehand how many IP's the voters used. 
Please don't tell me that this use case is improbable - it is real, I have to do it and got stuck :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, this is not a short answer, but I verified this in the Django shell and from the few tests I ran it appears to be counting correctly.

I'm assuming you have a model that can be simplified to this:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answertext = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Vote(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=None)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

If I understand your question correctly, we now want to count the number of votes for an answer - limiting the number of times a single IP can vote to 10.

I'll break down the various components and give the complete statement at the end.

First, we filter out a particular answer. You probably want somethings specific here - I just took all the "Yes" answers. We annotate with the count so we get all the Yes answers listed with the voting IPs and the number of times those IPs voted:

```
Vote.objects.filter(answer__answertext='Yes').values('ip').annotate(ipcount=Count('id'))
```

Next we need to limit any IPs with a count greater than 10 to a maximum of 10 votes. We do this using the Case and When expressions. Basically this says give us a new field that is equal to the vote count from an IP when the count is lesser or equal then 10 and limit the new field to 10 if the IP vote count was greater than 10.

```
.annotate(limitedipcount = Case(
    When(ipcount__lte=10, then='ipcount'), 
    When(ipcount__gt=10, then=10), 
    output_field=IntegerField())
)
```

Finally, we need to sum up this new 'limitedipcount' and we do this with a simple aggregate expression:

```
.aggregate(totallimitedipcount=Sum('limitedipcount'))
```

If you put all of that together you get something like this:

```
Vote.objects.filter(answer__answertext='Yes')
    .values('ip')
    .annotate(ipcount=Count('id'))
    .annotate(limitedipcount = Case(
        When(ipcount__lte=10, then='ipcount'), 
        When(ipcount__gt=10, then=10),
        output_field=IntegerField())
    )
    .aggregate(totallimitedipcount=Sum('limitedipcount'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I ended up writing a helper function with a limit as a parameter (default is None), that builds the dictionary {ip1: num_of_votes1, ip2: num_of_votes2}. To build this dictionary, the function iterates through all the votes for the given answer and each time checks the ip of a vote, deciding whether the ip is already in the dictionary and if the limit for a given IP has been reached and if not - augmenting value for a given key.At the end I sum up the values - `sum(my_dict.values())` and return it.

This is probably a very brute force solution so if anybody knows anything better, please post it.

Comment: My solution should do it and it's django-y too :)